# Total derivative. Combining two terms

Tags: partial-derivative

I will appreciate greatly if somebody could explain me how the two terms on the left are combined to form a total derivative? The first term on the left changed by using r=r_2*sin(phi). But the book says that there two terms that are combined.

This is not a homework, but a self-study.

[image]

Comment: what do you get if you differentiate $\frac{d}{d\phi}[(rN_{\phi})\sin\phi]$ using the product rule?

Comment: If I am not mistaken we get: r*sin(phi) + r*N*cos(phi). 
What do you suggest next, then?

Comment: Nope, try again. My point is that if you differentiate whats on the second line, you get exactly what's on the first line. That's why they say "combine the two terms".

Comment: based on the what's written, no $N$ is a function of $\phi$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. Now it makes sense. I have never met this formulation before.
As we speak, I would like to ask another question: 
Can you recommend a book that goes mainly on application of calculus and DEs? I.e. application for real life examples and engineering

Comment: You should really ask that in a separate question. I do not have experience with books like that specifically (when starting out calculus, I pretty much just learnt from Khan Academy, and MIT lectures on physics), so you'll get better answers from others.

Comment: That OK. 
Again, I appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Sergey